# Viewpager, countdowntimer, common and same to all fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, countdowntimer

I have a `view-pager` class and another fragment class. I want a count down timer in `view-pager`.

How do I implement a count down timer which decrements value but isn't affected by sliding or changing views(fragments)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your viewpager in a LinearLayout (for example ) then add your widget with the count down timer below the viewpager.

```
<LinearLayout>
   <ViewPager/>
   <Widget/>
</LinearLayout>
```